# Redirect Youtube channel main page to videos section the proper way using regex

Tags: regex

I made a regex rule using [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) that each time I get on a youtube channel it will redirect me to the videos section. The rule I made is this:

```
/https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/(.+)/ig
```

Substitute with:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/$1/videos
```

Having this as a test string:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/random_name1234
```

, I get this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/random_name1234/videos
```

The problem comes when I refresh the page by mistake. So, if the URL is already:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/random_name1234/videos
```

, I get:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/random_name1234/videos/videos
```

If I am in the playlists section of the channel and I refresh the page, I get:

```
https://www.youtube.com/channel/random_name1234/playlists/videos
```

How can I address this problem by modifying the regex pattern? I had several attempts at it, but I failed since I'm not so good at regex.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `/https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/([^\/]+)/ig`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've just tested it, and when I refresh the page while I'm at the videos section, it works, the URL doesn't get changed. But when I want to go to any other section of the channel, I get redirected to the videos section.

Comment: Try `/https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/([^\/]+)(?!\/videos(?:$|\/))(?=$|\/)/gi`, see https://regex101.com/r/Gr5qJA/1

Comment: It still doesn't work as I wanted it to. It still redirects me to the videos section when I try another section of the channel. But @TomLord's answer was the one I was looking for. Still, thank you for trying to help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `.*` is going to match on **anything** -- including if you're already on the `/videos` page, or some other section like `/playlist`, `/community`, etc.

You can make the regex more restrictive by saying "only match on non-forward-slash characters", to ensure that the URL in question is actually the main channel page.

Try this:

```
/https\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/channel\/([^\/]+)\/?$/ig
```

- `[^\/]+` means "one or more characters that's not a forward slash".
- `\/?` means "optionally a forward slash", in case there's a trailing one at the end of the URL.
- `$` means "end of string", so the regex won't match on longer URLs like `https://www.youtube.com/channel/xxxxx/about`

Comment: Similarly, you could use a character set like `\w+` ("only letters, numbers and underscores"), instead of `.+`, to prevent the pattern from matching *anything* (including more forward slashes).

Comment: If you add `$` at the end, why use `g` without `m`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Fair point about the missing `/m`. Although I think really, this isn't meant to be a multi-line match at all - so the `/g` is just redundant. Also, it does depend on which language (i.e. the regex flavour) is being used; sometimes `$` can mean "end of line" instead of "end of string".

Comment: @TomLord Yep, it's only used for a single-line match.